# ItemsSource doesn't show/bind when ObservableCollection is filled before loading the page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, itemssource

I have a carouselview, in that view I have an ObservableCollection binded as an itemssource. I am able to bind the collection and it would show when I execute the viewmodel's command in the OnAppearing event.

Code that works:

**Second Page**

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{

     public Coll(bool hard, string subject)
     {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = (DataSelectionViewModel)BindingContext;

            vm.Hard = hard;
            vm.Subject = subject;
            /* had to set "hard" and "subject" here again, otherwise data won't load */
     }

     protected override async void OnAppearing()
     {
         var vm = (DataSelectionViewModel)BindingContext;
         base.OnAppearing();
         await vm.LoadData.ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
     }
}
```

**The viewmodel for second page**

```
public class DataSelectionViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   private string subject;
   public string Subject { get => subject; set => SetProperty(ref subject, value); }

   private bool hard;
   public bool Hard { get => hard; set => SetProperty(ref hard, value); }

   public ObservableCollection<Items> FilteredData { get; set; }

   public UserSelectionViewModel()
   {
            _dataStore = DependencyService.Get<IDataStore>();

            LoadData= new AsyncAwaitBestPractices.MVVM.AsyncCommand(FilterData);

            FilteredData = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
   }
   public async Task FilterData()
   {
            FilteredData.Clear();
            var filtereddata = await _dataStore.SearchData(Hard, Subject).ConfigureAwait(false);
            foreach (var data in filtereddata)
            { 
                FilteredData.Add(data);
            }
   }  
}
```

**First Page where second page gets Hard and Subject values**

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var vm = (BaseViewModel)BindingContext;

   vm.Hard = HardButtonSelected == Hard;
   vm.Subject = vm.Subject.ToLower();

   await Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage(vm.Hard, vm.Subject));
   
}
```

So I want to change my code so that if I press the button on the first page, data instantly starts to filter and add to the ObservableCollection and when it's finished, then navigate to the second page. However if I try to load it to the BaseViewModel and then get the data from the second viewmodel it won't show the data.

Code that doesn't work:

**Second Page**

```
public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{

     public SecondPage()
     {
            InitializeComponent();
     }
}
```

**The viewmodel for second page**

```
public class DataSelectionViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

   public ObservableCollection<Items> FilteredData { get; set; }

   public UserSelectionViewModel()
   {

            FilteredData = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
   }
}
```

**BaseViewModel**

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string subject;
   public string Subject { get => subject; set => SetProperty(ref subject, value); }

   private bool hard;
   public bool Hard { get => hard; set => SetProperty(ref hard, value); }

   public ObservableCollection<Items> FilteredData { get; set; }

   /* BaseViewModel has implementation of SetProperty */
}
```

**First Page where second page gets Hard and Subject values**

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var vm = (BaseViewModel)BindingContext;

   vm.Hard = HardButtonSelected == Hard;
   vm.Subject = vm.Subject.ToLower();
}
```

**First Page viewmodel**

```
    public class FirstPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        public IAsyncCommand MehetButtonClickedCommand { get; }
        readonly IPageService pageService;
        readonly IFeladatokStore _feladatokStore;
        public FeladatValasztoViewModel()
        {
            _dataStore = DependencyService.Get<IDataStore>();
            ButtonClickedCommand = new AsyncCommand(ButtonClicked);

            pageService = DependencyService.Get<IPageService>();
        }

        private async Task ButtonClicked()
        {
            await FilterData();

            await pageService.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
        }

        private async Task FilterData()
        {
            FilteredData.Clear();
            var datas = await _dataStore.SearchData(Subject, Hard).ConfigureAwait(false);
            foreach (var data in datas)
            {
                FilteredData.Add(data);
            }
        }
```

So basically this gives a null exception error. I also tried giving the ObservableCollection as an argument for SecondPage(ObservableCollection x) and that did work, but because I had to make another ObservableCollection for it and copy from one to another it stopped being async and froze for a couple of seconds. So my question is how can I make this async?

Comment: please post the code that doesn't work so we can help you fix it.  Posting the code that does work doesn't really help us understand the problem.

Comment: Edited my question, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: you are not passing any data between the pages

Comment: And how can I fix this with an async method?

Comment: "async" isn't some magic wand that fixes all problems.  As I noted in your earlier question, you have to do some digging to determine where the root cause of the problem is.  Here you need to pass the data between the pages.  If doing that causes another problem, then you need to track down the source of that problem and fix it.

Comment: *"I also tried giving the ObservableCollection as an argument for SecondPage(ObservableCollection x) and that did work, but because I had to make another ObservableCollection for it and copy from one to another"*. Passing it as a parameter is a good approach. That copy should take negligible amount of time, so I am sure what you tried is fixable. Add a new section with that code.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid delay, build the new collection in a private variable. *Then* set the property to that variable:

```cs
// Constructor with parameter
public SomeClass(IList<Items> data)
{
    SetFilteredDataCopy(data);
}

public ObservableCollection<Items> FilteredData { get; set; }

private void SetFilteredDataCopy(IList<Items> src)
{
    var copy = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
    foreach (var item in src)
        copy.Add(item);
    FilteredData = copy;
    //MAYBE OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredData));
}
```